# Performing a sum on rows with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query like this

```
select sum(t1.quantity) - sum(t2.quantity * SELECT CASE WHEN (condition on t3.status) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ),0)
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
inner join table3 t3 on t2.key = t3.key
```

Basically what it do is a subtraction between the first some and a second some of t2.quantity that are in rows that have a condition on the column t3.status (for example t3.status > 2).

But I am getting

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Is there a way to do this without adding extra join or other query?

Comment: do you mean when conditon is true , then t2.quantity * 1 , else t2.quantity*0 ?

Comment: yes so it will be the some of quantity where the condition is verified

Comment: The select statement you posted is not valid. It seems there is some extra stuff going on there, perhaps an ISNULL? You also seem to have a subquery but the syntax is not valid there either. I think maybe you have simplified this so much for posting that you left out a lot of details.

Comment: we can't see your query, but you might want to try writing a query with the sub query in it, but with no aggregate functions, then query the query to give the aggregates

Comment: hold on, what if you just do ...Sum(t2.quantity * CASE WHEN (condition on t3.status) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: @AndrewDeighton it works the error was in the select that is inside the sum function I HAVE TO REMOVE IT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. You don't need a `select` again when using `case` as `t3` is already joined.

```
select sum(t1.quantity) - sum(t2.quantity * CASE WHEN t3.status > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
inner join table3 t3 on t2.key = t3.key
```